# how to make Dell powervault 715N to boot linux OS(Zentyal/pfsense) using hard disk instead of PXE?

Tags: linux

All the question is about Dell powervault 715N.
as my research installing/booting linux OS(Zentyal/pfsense) in  is possible using PXE but is it possible to boot from hard disk as i using UNetbootin to do it. But it fail as it stop half way after detecting the hard disk.

Is there any to do it so that linux is able to boot from internal hard disk using Dell powervault 715N.|

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Zentyal, but pfSense is BSD-based, not Linux. It can be installed by simply uncompressing the provided disk image and writing it directly to the hard drive using `dd`. This is the preferred method of installation.

A LiveCD installer is also available from the pfSense mirrors, but I have not personally used it.

Comment: i use the `liveCD` but fail n now i am trying the 1st way that u have suggested, hopefully work.

Comment: itried the 1st way n it is the same, it hang half way when reached the pfsense menu. Oh ya, i am using pfsense and not zentyal. Do there have other way to solve it?